# Batch finding multiple newest folders

Tags: batch-file

Hey guys im new to batch scripting and have a question 
I have a script to find the newst folder created in a given path

```
@echo off
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') DO (
    SET a=%%i
    GOTO :found
)
echo No subfolder found
goto :eof
:found



set audioid=%a% 

echo Most recent subfolder: %audioid%
pause
```

I would now like to find the 4 newest folders and im not sure how to go about it.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a piece of code that does the trick. It iterates through the most recent folders returned by the `dir` command (each returned on one line), and after it encounters the 4th it stops (if there are more than 4 folders).

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions, enabledelayedexpansion
set /a _IDX=0
set /a _MAX_ENTRIES=4

FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /ad-h /t:c /o-d') DO (
    echo Most recent subfolder: %%i
    set /A _IDX=!_IDX! + 1
    if !_IDX! geq !_MAX_ENTRIES! (
        goto :eof
    )
)
```

If you want a different number of most recent folders, just change `_MAX_ENTRIES` value.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example which first assigns the names of the four newest **created** subfolders to environment variables and then outputs them.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FolderIndex=0"

for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD-H /B /O-D /T:C 2^>nul') do (
    set /A FolderIndex+=1
    set "NewestFolder#!FolderIndex!=%%I"
    if !FolderIndex! == 4 goto FoundFolders
)

if not %FolderIndex% == 0 goto FoundFolders
echo No subfolder found.
goto EndBatch

:FoundFolders
set NewestFolder#

:EndBatch
endlocal
pause
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`